# Provision site with pnp package gives file not found error

Tags: pnp-powershell, pnp-provision

I would like to move the provisioning templates to SharePoint Online so I need to convert them to pnp package. I try to convert a folder with provisioning files using the `Convert-PnPFolderToProvisioningTemplate` command and in my test scenario there's something that's not working.

In my template, I have a web part page, that is also my home page:

```
<pnp:File Src="SitePages\classic.aspx" Folder="{site}/SitePages" Overwrite="true" Level="Draft">
```

The file exists, and when I extract the content of the generated pnp file, I can see that it is also included in the mapping.

```
<x:String x:Key="119c05d8-0d20-4fb0-9730-2a83ed3993a4.aspx">SitePages/classic.aspx</x:String>
```

Still, when I apply the template, I receive a file not found error and the file is not copied.

What is the correct way to include aspx files that should be copied to the SitePages library?